# How does Bitdefender's Crypto-Ransomware Vaccine work?

Tags: security, virus

I have read responses (66 currently) but still have no idea how [this tool](https://labs.bitdefender.com/2016/03/combination-crypto-ransomware-vaccine-released/) works.

"Razvan Stoica says:
It’s a vaccine, but it can (and probably will) be updated against new strains, hence the need to run at startup. It does not monitor behavior, it just uses some tricks to prevent those specific families of ransomware from infecting your system."

I've read [articles](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3049179/security/free-bitdefender-tool-prevents-locky-other-ransomware-infections-for-now.html) and google it but still want to know how does it actually do? 
"The new Bitdefender tool takes advantage of these ransomware checks by making it appear as if computers are already infected with current variants of Locky, TeslaCrypt or CTB-Locker. This prevents those programs from infecting them again."

What does it "vaccines"? What part of Windows tells ransomware it is already infected by it?

Comment: i wouldn't be surprised if they're checking certain files, boot records or processes to determine if target is already infected. a similar trick can be used to "vaccine" usb drives by creating a read only autorun which would prevent a virus from writing its own ( a low quality virus may be :) )

Comment: Most of the variants of ransomware have conditions one which it will actually infect the machine, if those conditions are not meet, then it does not encrypt the files.  They want to get paid and these conditions being true, prevent that from happening, for instance a good chunk of ransomware variants only work on MBR partitions, so they ignore, systems running on a GPT partition.  In the end unless Bitdefender shares the information we are just guessing.  *Contact Bitdefender and ask.*

Comment: @Ramhound Tnx. I've just left the response and interested in their answer. If they don't answer I'll contact them some other way.

Answer (score 4):

Bitdefender's Crypto-Ransomware Vaccine inserts **recognition markers** that ransomware uses to check if it has already infected a system, for example a *registry entry*.

The Locky Trojan is an executable file and once launched, the Trojan checks for the presence and the contents of the below [registry keys](http://secufeed.com/item/1484_locky-the-encryptor-taking-the-world-by-storm).

```
|            Path                         |    Type     |    Type       |
|:----------------------------------------|------------:|:-------------:|
| HKEY_CURRENT_USERSoftwareLockyid        |  REG_SZ     |  Infection ID    
| HKEY_CURRENT_USERSoftwareLockypubkey    |  REG_BINARY |  Public RSA key in MSBLOB format  
| HKEY_CURRENT_USERSoftwareLockypaytext   |  REG_BINARY |  Text shown to the victim   
| HKEY_CURRENT_USERSoftwareLockycompleted |  REG_DWORD  |  Status (whether encryption is completed)
```

*Not related to question but can help a lot of people that have been victims*:
If you want to know which type of ransomware attacked you there is a [site](https://id-ransomware.malwarehunterteam.com/) that could help you with that. Sometimes there are decryption keys available online and this site will give you link where you can download decrypter.

I'll update the answer with more information...

Comment: Ive wondered if one could Prevent the system from getting infected by accident in the future if the Registry Keys were already set to status of infected (Basically spoofed into thinking the system is infected so it does not even try.)? Or is the Registry keys different per PC?

Comment: I don't think they are different per PC, they have different values but I don't think they are important if you want to fool the ransomware. Again not sure... And registry entrys can be only one of several markers that ransomware checks.

Comment: 2016 (at least) also marks the folders you wish to protect as read only.